# Python Pyo midi keyboard simulate

Tags: python, keyboard, midi, sound-synthesis, midi-interface

I looking to develop a synth with python and Pyo.
I'd like to use my computer keyboard as a midi keyboard to play melodies.

How can I fake my computer keyboard as a midi keyboard?

thx

Comment: What OS are you on? Linux?

Comment: Hi, I'm on windows 10

Comment: [This[(http://vmpk.sourceforge.net/#Download) should do it then. There are others, if you look for them.

Answer (score 0):

There are many virtual midi keyboard you can install.
On Linux, using jack:

- http://vmpk.sourceforge.net/
- http://jack-keyboard.sourceforge.net/

More generally, search for "virtual midi keyboards" for your particular OS.

Comment: Ok but can I use directly my keyboard without installing this kind of software?

Comment: What do you mean? Pyo is a library to program instruments using the python language. It can understand midi input and use it to control the instruments and effects you use in your program. Then sending the program midi information will affect its behavior(e.g. the pitch, amplitude of the notes). Your computer keyboard doesn't by itself generate midi information. You have to convert your keyboard's signals to midi information, and you need a virtual midi interface to do that.